# JScrollPane doesn't show the panel contained in it in the right way

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I would use a JScrollPane in Java Swing to contain a Panel filled with other panel.
I've created my JPanel and I filled it with 6 other panels, which represent a card in a game board.
Then I've created my JScrollpane and I set my JPanel as a new viewport but in runtime the scrollbars don't appear and my JPanel is cut and JScrollPane shows only 4 cards on 6.
Obviously i've checked my big panel's size and it is greater than the JScrollPane's but it doesn't work.

```
Double politicRelX=0.0686275;
Double politicRelY=0.39726;
Dimension politicDim=//dimension of my JScrollPane
JScrollPane scrollCards=new JScrollPane();

scrollCards.setBounds(//politicDimBounds);

playerTab.add(scrollCards);

JLabel politicsCards=new JLabel();

politicsCards.setName("politicsCards");
politicsCards.setLayout(null);
int dinstanceX=(int)(0.028634*politicDim.width);
int dinstanceY=(int)(0.02395*politicDim.height);
int space=(int)(0.028634*politicDim.width);
Dimension cardDim=new Dimension(//cardDimension);

for(int i=0;i<player.getCardsOwned().size();i++){
    JPanel card=new ImagePanel(player.getCardsOwned().get(i).getImagePath(),cardDim);
    card.setName("politicsCard"+i);
    card.setBounds(dinstanceX, dinstanceY, cardDim.width, cardDim.height);
    dinstanceX+=cardDim.width+space;
    politicsCards.add(card);
}

scrollCards.setViewportView(politicsCards);
```

So, what I've forgotten?

Comment: `politicsCards.setLayout(null);` -- and there's your problem. Yet another reason to avoid null layouts like the plague.

Comment: As per MadProgrammer: "The JScrollPane relies on the information provided by the layout manager to make determination about when to show scroll bars."

Comment: I've also tried with BoxLayout or BorderLayout, but the result is the same..